# Fastest function for TCanvas.CopyRect

Tags: delphi

I want to scale some sub images from an original image.
I need to use `TCanvas.CopyRect` function for about 5,000 times and it is very slow (from a simple BMP image).

Do you know any other method that is faster that simple `TCanvas.CopyRect` method for the same job?

Again the job is to stretch some rects (different rects, to the same size, exactly windowing) from an original image for about 5,000 times.

Edit: I tested it with **1,700** images and that takes **20** seconds.

Big edit, i don't use copyrect because i found it is useless:

```
Uses Classes,SysUtils,Windows,Graphics,HaarFeature_unit,Dialogs;

Type TAlgorithm = class(TObject)
   protected
      bmBitmap:TBitmap;

      Haar:THaarFeature;

      vRects:array of TRect;
      vWebcamMatrix:TWebcamMatrix;
      iWebcamMatrixWidth,iWebcamMatrixHeight:integer;

      Procedure ClearList;
      Procedure DrawList;
  public
      Procedure Process(bmBitmap:TBitmap);
   private
      iMinWidth,iMinHeight,iMaxWidth,iMaxHeight,iDistX,iDistY:integer;
      procedure ProcessRect(iLeft,iTop,iRight,iBottom:integer);
      Procedure AddSolution(iLeft,iTop,iRight,iBottom:integer);
      Procedure ConstructorWebcamMatrix;
   published
      Constructor Create(iMinWidth,iMinHeight,iMaxWidth,iMaxHeight,iDistX,iDistY:integer; sHaarPath:string; iWhite,iBlack:integer);
end;

implementation
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Procedure TAlgorithm.AddSolution(iLeft,iTop,iRight,iBottom:integer);
begin
   SetLength(vRects,Length(vRects)+1);
   vRects[High(vRects)]:=Rect(iLeft,iTop,iRight,iBottom);
end;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Procedure TALgorithm.ProcessRect(iLeft,iTop,iRight,iBottom:integer);
begin

end;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Procedure TAlgorithm.ConstructorWebcamMatrix;
var i,j:integer;
    pvScanLine:PIntegerArray;
begin
   for i := 0 to self.bmBitmap.Height-1 do
   begin
      pvScanLine:=bmBitmap.ScanLine[i];
      for j := 0 to self.bmBitmap.Width-1 do
         vWebcamMatrix[i,j]:=GetRValue(pvScanLine[j]);
   end;
   self.iWebcamMatrixWidth:=self.bmBitmap.Width;
   self.iWebcamMatrixHeight:=self.bmBitmap.Height;
end;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Procedure TAlgorithm.Process(bmBitmap:TBitmap);
var iLeft,iTop,iRight,Bottom,iCount:integer;
begin
   self.bmBitmap:=bmBitmap;
   self.bmBitmap.PixelFormat:=pf32Bit;
   if bmBitmap = NIL then exit;

   self.ConstructorWebcamMatrix;

   self.ClearList;

   iCount:=0;
   iLeft:=0;
   while iLeft < iWebcamMatrixWidth-iMinWidth do
   begin

      iTop:=0;
      while iTop<iWebcamMatrixHeight-iMinHeight  do
      begin

         iRight:=iMinWidth;

         while (iRight < iMaxWidth)and(iLeft+iRight<iWebcamMatrixWidth) do
         begin

            iBottom:=iMinHeight;
            while (iBottom < iMaxHeight)and(iTop+iBottom<iWebcamMatrixHeight) do
            begin
               if self.Haar.Execute(iLeft,iTop,iLeft+iRight,iTop+iBottom) then
                  AddSolution(iLeft,iTop,iLeft+iRight,iTop+iBottom);

               //iCount:=iCount+1;

               Inc(iBottom,iDistY);
            end;

            iCount:=iCount+1;

            inc(iRight,iDistX);
         end;

         iTop:=iTop+iDistY;
      end;

      iLeft:=iLeft+iDistX;
   end;

   self.DrawList;

   //
   //ShowMessage(IntToStr(iCount));
   //Verify algorithm
end;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Procedure TAlgorithm.ClearList;
begin
   SetLength(self.vRects,0);
end;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Procedure TAlgorithm.DrawList;
var i:integer;
begin
   self.bmBitmap.Canvas.Brush.Style:=bsClear;
   self.bmBitmap.Canvas.Pen.Color:=clRed;
   for i := 0 to High(self.vRects) do
     self.bmBitmap.Canvas.Rectangle(vRects[i].Left,vRects[i].Top,vRects[i].Right,vRects[i].Bottom);
end;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Constructor TAlgorithm.Create(iMinWidth,iMinHeight,iMaxWidth,iMaxHeight,iDistX,iDistY:integer; sHaarPath:String; iWhite,iBlack:integer);
begin
   inherited Create;

//   bmRect:=TBitmap.Create;
//   bmRect.PixelFormat:=pf32Bit;
   self.iMinWidth:=iMinWidth;
   self.iMinHeight:=iMinHeight;
   self.iMaxWidth:=iMaxWidth;
   self.iMaxHeight:=iMaxHeight;
   self.iDistX:=iDistX;
   self.iDistY:=iDistY;

   Haar:=THaarFeature.Create(sHaarPath,@self.vWebcamMatrix,iWhite,iBlack);
end;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
end.
```

and HaarClass

```
Uses Classes,SysUtils,Messages,Dialogs,Windows,Graphics;

Type TWebcamMatrix = array [0..512,0..512] of integer;
Type PWebcamMatrix = ^ TWebcamMatrix;

Type THaarFeature = class(TObject)
   public
      vHaarMatrix:array of array of integer;
      pvMatrixArray:PWebcamMatrix;

      iRectWidth,iRectHeight:integer;
      Procedure Load(sPath:String);
      Function Execute(iLeft,iTop,iRight,iBottom:integer):Boolean;
   private
      iWhite,iBlack:integer;
   published
      Constructor Create(sPath:string; pvMatrixArray:PWebcamMatrix; iWhite,iBlack:integer);
end;

implementation
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function THaarFeature.Execute(iLeft,iTop,iRight,iBottom:integer):Boolean;
var i,j,a,b,an,bn:integer;
    x,y,fi,fj:real;
begin
   if self.pvMatrixArray = NIL then exit;

   a:=0; an:=0;
   b:=0; an:=0;
   iRectWidth:=iRight-iLeft;
   iRectHeight:=iBottom-iTop;

   y:=High(self.vHaarMatrix) / iRectHeight ;
   x:=High(self.vHaarMatrix[0]) / iRectWidth ;

   fi:=0;
   for i := iTop to iBottom do
   begin
      fj:=0;
      for j := iLeft to iRight do
      begin

         if (vHaarMatrix[Trunc(fi)][Trunc(fj)]=1) then
         begin
            a:=a+self.pvMatrixArray^[i,j];
            an:=an+1;
         end else
         begin
            b:=b+self.pvMatrixArray^[i,j];
            bn:=bn+1;
         end;

         fj:=fj+x;
      end;
      fi:=fi+y;
   end;

   if an=0 then a:=100
   else a:=a div an;

   if bn=0 then b:=0
   else b:=b div bn;

   if (a>self.iWhite)and(b<self.iBlack) then
   begin
      Result:=true;
   end else
   begin
      Result:=false;
   end;
end;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Procedure THaarFeature.Load(sPath:String);
var fIn:Text;
    i,j,n,m,nr:integer;
begin

   if (FileExists(sPath) = false) then
   begin
     MessageDlg('File not exists',mtError,[mbOK],1);
     exit;
   end;

   try
     AssignFile(fIn,sPath); System.Reset(fIn);

     n:=0;
     while not eof(fIn) do
     begin
         m:=0;
         while not eoln(fIn) do
         begin
            read(fin,nr);
            inc(m);
         end;
         readln(fin);
         inc(n);
      end;

      CloseFile(fIn);


      SetLength(self.vHaarMatrix,n,m);

      AssignFile(fIn,sPath); System.Reset(fIn);

      for i := 0 to high(self.vHaarMatrix) do
      begin
        for j := 0 to high(self.vHaarMatrix[0]) do
        begin
           read(fin,vHaarMatrix[i][j]);
        end;
        readln(fin);
      end;

      CloseFile(fIn);

   except
      MessageDlg('Error assigning file to read haar matrix',mtError,[mbOK],1);
   end;
end;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Constructor THaarFeature.Create(sPath:string; pvMatrixArray:PWebcamMatrix; iWhite,iBlack:integer);
begin
   inherited Create;

   self.iWhite:=iWhite;
   self.pvMatrixArray:=pvMatrixArray;
   self.iBlack:=iBlack;
   self.Load(sPath);
end;
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
end.
```

Parameters for
objAlgorithm:=TAlgorithm.Create(30,30,60,60,9,9 _sPath, 200,50);

For these parameters it works very well, but if i would like to improve and make smaller the iDistX, and iDistY to 8 or 7 it is very slow, and the bitmap must have a 128x128 pixels. Trully it is a polinomial complexity , it is about n^6.

Description of the algorithm:
It takes a lot of windows(now it doesn't scale anymore), and using a haar function it calculate a sum of pixels from a matrix). Like a face recognition(it is the same priciple, but currently i don't have the neural network, and just the haar function and not in the same porpose)

I use that strange reading of haar matrix because in that file it doesn't include the length of haar function.

Comment: `CopyRect` calls `StretchBlt`. That's pretty well optimised. What makes you thing it is reasonable to expect better performance? How slow is slow?

Comment: If you stretch the same image over and over, you should really look at caching the image, instead of recalculating from scratch.

Comment: Maybe multithreading can help a little by distributing the image processing to every processor core.

Comment: @hubalu Not if the copying all modifies a single image, but of course we don't really know anything.

Comment: It's not slow at all. The only possible speed-up I could imagine for this case, is if you somehow managed to transfer the entire bitmap to the graphics card, and then have all the 17.000 stretches done directly from the graphics card memory, by the GPU. Then maybe you could see a speed increase. Otherwise not, I think.

Comment: I made a mistake, 1,700 copyrect it takes me about 20 seconds. Not 17,000

Comment: @user558126: That makes it 11.8 milliseconds per image, or 85 images per second, which is still pretty quick. We can't tell you anything else without you giving us a lot more information about how much faster it needs to be, what exactly is happening, and exactly which piece of code needs optimizing.

Comment: So where in the world is your bottle-neck? is it `Process`?  and why are you using `pf32Bit` format for? I really think you need to delete this Q, and post the bottle-neck code only because it's a big salad right now...